# Create monochromatic tray icon for OS X using QSystemTrayIcon

Tags: macos, qt, qt5, system-tray

[OS X asks apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/ToolbarIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000957-CH89-SW3) to use a 19x19px monochomatic PDF as a tray icon in order to adapt a system default color based on the user's theme.

> Use a template image to represent a menu bar extra. In General system preferences, users can change the menu bar (and Dock) to a dark appearance. [...]

Can that be done using [QSystemTrayIcon](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html)?

As far as I can see the underlying QIcon class does not support PDF.

---

At the moment I am using a black SVG, which is displayed in pure black, causing a very unnatural appearance.

Default theme:

[image: SVG on default theme]

Dark theme:

[image: SVG on dark theme]

Comment: If there is a way to get system theme colors, you could colorize your icon. Just have the shape as alpha, and fill the color channels with the desired values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its known [issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42109) of QT which going to be fixed in version 5.6

Comment: This does not add any value. From my original question *As far as I can see the underlying QIcon class does not support PDF.*

Comment: Have you tried use something other than PDF in QIcon? Because as I noticed with link to apple docs, PDF - its not Apple requirement to displaying icon in the Status Menu.

Comment: Jap but the image formats are not monochrome and do not change with the system theme (see black icon in dark theme).

Comment: For doing that in Cocoa uses setTemplate: method of NSImage object. Maybe QIcon have similar property? Documentation of setTemplate: says that you can use black and transparent for doing night mode (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/setTemplate:)

Comment: Great, thanks. Could you put that into another answer?

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in Qt 5.6. Just remember to set the `isMask` attribute on the QIcon like this: `myQIcon.setIsMask(true)` and then `mySysTray.setIcon(myQIcon)`